# Trying to disable vscode new parent code lines but can't?

Tags: html, laravel, visual-studio-code, laravel-blade

[image]

New feature came in vscode recently but I don't need it right now, how can I disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search the property Sticky scroll in vscode settings to disable it
[image]